# Facebook Application Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I create a demo application to request photos from facebook. I created an application token like this : 549933848476397|4a584ce5fda19cba2ed6630ed78ba8f4. But when use this request URL https://graph.facebook.com/1417833425116725/photos?access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}. It's does not work. Please help me. Actually When I use user token for this request, It's work ok.

Comment: application token and access token are different!

Comment: Did you mean that I can't use application token for that request?

Comment: NEVER NEVER NEVER show your app access token in public!

Comment: app token and access token are NOT different. in fact, there are "app access tokens", "user access tokens" and "page access tokens".

Comment: I know there are many kinds of access token. But my problem is, when I user the URL: https://graph.facebook.com/1417833425116725/photos?access_token={user_access_token}, it's works OK!. But when I used https://graph.facebook.com/1417833425116725/photos?access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}. It does not work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Page is restricted somehow (age, location), you can only use a User or Page Access Token to get data like photos of the Page. The App Access Token got no relation to any User, so Facebook can´t detect if the User is even allowed to see the Page.

I am 100% sure the Page is restricted btw, you get an "Unsupported get request" error when trying to access the Page ID directly with the Graph API, and that usually happens when the Page is restricted.

Just try another Page with that exact same App Access Token, for example:

```
/bladauhu/photos
```

...works without any problem. Another sign that your Page is indeed restricted.

TL;DR: For this specific Page, you MUST use a User Token or Page Token.

Comment: This page is no restricted, I can access this page with user access token. https://graph.facebook.com/1417833425116725/photos?access_token={user_access_token}.

Comment: of course you can access it with a user token, if it´s restricted you just can´t use an app token as i said. are you 100% sure the page is not restricted? meaning: are you admin of the page and do you KNOW it´s not restricted?

Comment: i just did some testing, the page is restricted for sure. edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much luschn. This Infomation help me a lots. So Is there any way for my application request photos form this page without user_access_token? Beacause user_access_token is expried every 2 months.

Comment: the only way to make it work with an app token is to remove the restriction on the page - of course you have to be page admin for that. if you want to keep the restriction, you can also use an extended page token - you have to be a page admin for that too, of course. extended page tokens are valid forever.